# How can I have the vim keybindings in normal mode and the standard pycharm keybindings in insert mode possible?

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I love to use the vim keybindings to navigate text, to move, delete and change it. But when I'm in Insert-Mode I'd like to have the normal IDE-keybindings like CNTRL-V, CNTRL-P, CNTRL-C, etc. back.

Is it possible to configure IdeaVim that way? I tried to switch the vim plugin on and off, but then I have to additionally leave insert mode all the time and also things like cw etc don't automatically leave drop me into Insert-Mode...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure conflicting shortcuts in "File | Settings | Other Settings | Vim Emulation". It's not possible to use some IDE shortcuts only in a particular Vim mode. You have to choose either an IDE handler or a Vim emulation handler for a shortcut.